# How to fix '403 forbidden' error while connecting wordpress and zapier?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-location, zapier

I am trying to connect wordpress and zapier using zapier app but i am getting 403 forbidden error. For fix this i added some below setting in my nginx conf file.

```
location = /xmlrpc.php {
    #start ip
    include zapierips;
    #end ip
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

In zapierips.conf i added some zapier ips like:

```
allow 23.20.0.0/14;
allow 34.192.0.0/12;
allow 34.224.0.0/12;
allow 35.153.0.0/16;
allow 35.168.0.0/13;
allow 50.16.0.0/15;
allow 50.19.0.0/16;
allow 52.0.0.0/15;
```

Please help me sort out this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Check your question, the include filename differs. Check the configuration using `nginx -t` and/or `nginx -T`. If this location is expected to execute PHP files, you will need additional statements (look at your `location ~ \.php$` block - or similar).

Comment: Check your logs and see if the IP request is from the range you added or not